# beeline LDAP authentication with encrypted password file

Tags: authentication, hive, hadoop2, password-encryption, beeline

I am using Beeline CLI to connect HiveServer2. I am using following command to connect:

`beeline -u jdbc:hive2://myhost.abc.com:10000/default -n myuser -w pass_sa  -e "show tables;"`

Connection is successful and I am able to access the Hive database but here my password is not encrypted here I am trying to use encrypted password using password file.

I am going through with several link but having confusion with LDAP authentication and Encrypted password authentication and looking for help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned LDAP, I assume that you are using Kerberos and "myuser" is Active Directory or Kerberos realm account. You have to authenticate your user with "kinit" and then run beeline without user and password. Beeline should not ask for credentials.

Try to run those steps:

```
su - myuser
kinit (and type the "myuser" password)
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://myhost.abc.com:10000/default" -e "show tables;"
```

Comment: I will be using this command using Shell Script therefore I want to avoid pressing "enter". Any other options are available to encrypt password ??

Comment: I did a check - on my server after kinit the beeline did not ask for the password and just execute command. Check in your environment. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You need to fix the quotes. The valid command should be beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://myhost.abc.com:10000/default" -e "show tables;"

Comment: Hi Sandeep! If my suggestion was helpful, kindly mark it as the answer.